# Reproducing Singular Value Decompition in R

Tags: r, svd, decomposition, singular

I have an example word by document matrix (from Landauer and Dumais, 1997):

```
wxd <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
            1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1)
          ,12, 9)
rownames(wxd) <- c("human", "interface", "computer", "user", "system", 
               "response", "time", "EPS", "survey", "trees", "graph", "minors")
colnames(wxd) <- c(paste0("c", 1:5), paste0("m", 1:4))
```

I can perform Singular Value Decomposition on this matrix using the `svd()` function and have three matrices `U`, `S`, and `V`:

```
SVD <- svd(wxd)
U <- SVD$u
S <- diag(SVD$d)
V <- SVD$v
```

I can multiply these matrices and get my original matrix returned (within some small margin or error):

```
U %*% S %*% t(V)
```

I can also take the first two columns of the `U` and `V` matrices and the first two columns and rows of the `S` matrix to get the least squares best approximation of the original data. This fits with the results of the same procedure in the paper I mentioned above:

```
U[ , 1:2] %*% S[1:2, 1:2] %*% t(V[ , 1:2])
```

I am wanting to make sure I understand what this function is doing (as best as I am able), and I have been able to generate the `V` and `S` matrices to match those from the `svd()` function:

```
ATA <- t(wxd) %*% wxd
V2 <- eigen(ATA)$vectors

S2 <- sqrt(diag(eigen(ATA)$values))
```

But, the `U` matrix I generate has the same absolute values for the first 9 columns then adds an additional 3 columns. And some elements of this `U` matrix have different signs than the `U` matrix from the `svd()` function:

```
AAT <- wxd %*% t(wxd)
U2 <- eigen(AAT)$vectors
```

So my question is, why is the `U` matrix different than when I attempt to calculate it from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wxd` has rank of `9`. Therefore, your `AAT` only has `9` non-zero eigenvalues (the rest are very small `~1e-16`). For those zero eigenvalues, the eigenvectors are arbitrary as long as they span the subspace orthogonal to that spanned by the other eigenvectors in R^12.

Now, by default `svd` only computes `nu=min(n,p)` left singular vectors (similarly for right eigenvectors) where `n` is the number of rows and `p` is the number of columns in the input (see `?svd`). Therefore, you only get `9` left singular vectors. To generate all `12`, call `svd` with:

```
svd(wxd,nu=nrow(wxd))
```

However, those extra `3` left singular vectors will not correspond to those found with `eigen(AAT)$vectors` again because these eigenvectors are determined somewhat arbitrarily to span that orthogonal subspace.

As for why some of the signs have changed, recall that eigenvectors are only determined up to a scale factor. Although these eigenvectors are normalized, they may differ by a factor of `-1`. To check just divide one from `U` with the corresponding one from `U2`. You should get columns of all `1`s or `-1`s:

```
U[,1:9]/U2[,1:9]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
## [1,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [2,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [3,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [4,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [5,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [6,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [7,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [8,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
## [9,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
##[10,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
##[11,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
##[12,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1    1    1
```

---

#### Update to explain why Eigenvector is only determined up to a scale factor

This can be seen from the definition of the eigenvector. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors),

> In linear algebra, an eigenvector or characteristic vector of a linear transformation is a non-zero vector that does not change its direction when that linear transformation is applied to it.

In finite-dimensional vector space, the linear transformation is in terms of multiplying the vector with a square matrix `A`, and therefore the definition is (This is where I wish SO supports LaTeX markdown as this is not an equation in code; that is `*` is matrix-multiply here):

```
A * v = lambda * v
```

which is known as the *Eigenvalue Equation* for the matrix `A` where `lambda` is the eigenvalue associated with the eigenvector `v`. From this equation, it is clear that if `v` is an eigenvector of `A` then any `k * v` for some scalar `k` is also an eigenvector of `A` with associated eigenvalue `lambda`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I understand. So If I run `SVD <- svd(wxd,nu=nrow(wxd))` I can put my original matrix back together by using the first 9 columns of U (eg., `U[,1:9] %*% S %*% t(V)`). But, this doesn't seem to work with U2 (e.g., `U2[,1:9] %*% S2 %*% t(V2)`). Am I missing something?

Comment: @snarble: that is because unlike `svd`, `U2` and `V2` are computed via separate calls to `eigen` using `AAT` and `ATA` so that the left and right eigenvectors may be "mutually scaled" differently by "+/-1". If we correct this by multiplying `U2[,1:9]` by the correction `U[,1:9]/U2[,1:9]`, which are columns of all `1`s or `-1`s, and multiplying `V2` by `V/V2`, then we trivially get `(U2[,1:9] * U[,1:9] / U2[,1:9]) %*% S2 %*% t(V2 * V / V2)` which will recover `wxd`.

Comment: That is very helpful. How would I make sure my two matrices `U` and `V` are mutually scaled to be identical to the `svd` function?

Comment: @snarble: I don't believe you can. Let me ask you this: what are you really trying to achieve by recovering `wxd` from `U2` and `V2`?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I would like to write my own function to perform SVD so I can be sure I know what is happening, or at the very least I want to completely understand what is happening when I run `svd(wxd)`.

Comment: @snarble: I would seriously advise you **not** to do that. There are many numeric nuances to an implementation and even if you do it, no one will care because it has already been done in LAPACK. In fact, R links to LAPACK, which is written in Fortran. Instead I would read a good classic book on the topic such as Golub and Van Loan, *Matrix Computations*, 1983 to understand the algorithm.

Comment: Is there anyway you could go into a little bit more detail when you said "recall that eigenvectors are only determined up to a scale factor"?